# Как упаковать фон jpg в один файл exe Pyinstaller'ом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Вопрос: Есть код

```
C = Canvas(root, bg="blue", height=300, width=300)
filename = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\321.jpg")
background_label = Label(root, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
C.pack()
```

Как мне упаковать фон в один exe программы? Если собрать обычным методом ехе, то он будет подгружать картинку из папки, а если ее не будет- выдаст ошибку